# Display Data from Database to Label

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to display data (bank name) from database in a label.

Each user has four bank id in rate table. I want to retrieve their name from bank table. The user id is the session variable.

The query command is correct but when I add session variable the error is raised.

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> Source Error:
>   Line 26: str = "select bank_name from bank, rate, [user] where((bank.bank_id=rate.bank_id)and(user.user_id=rate.user_id='" + Session["UserName"] + "'";
>   Line 27: com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
>   Line 28: SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
>   Line 29:
>   Line 30: reader.Read();

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Displaying_Data_From_Db_to_Label
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdminConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string str;
        SqlCommand com;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
            str = "select bank_name from bank, rate, [user] where((bank.bank_id=rate.bank_id)and(user.user_id=rate.user_id='" + Session["UserName"] + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();
            labelname1.Text = reader["bank_name"].ToString();

            reader.Read();
            labelname2.Text = reader["bank_name"].ToString();

            reader.Read();
            labelname3.Text = reader["bank_name"].ToString();

            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Aspx markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Displaying_Data_From_Db_to_Label._Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <title>Untitled Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
     <asp:Label ID="labelname1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="labelage1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
     <asp:Label ID="labelname2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="labelage2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
     <asp:Label ID="labelname3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="labelage3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
     </div>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is the value of  `Session["UserName"]` when you debug through the code?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @paqogomez  Session["UserName"]  is a text that store from text box

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Your error would indicate that you have bad or no data in that value.  Use @THBBFT's answer, and debug through your code to see exactly its value.

Comment: If memory serves, Session is an old school specialized collection ... brb ...right `HttpSessionState`, with indexer that returns an `Object`.  So by assigning it to a string you are calling the implicit conversion to a string.  I'll update my example to add a place to attach a break point.

Comment: @paqogomez sorry ,i'm not proffisional....the error that appear when decleare string (((Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)))

Comment: @THBBFT's that right it return object.what can i do to fix that?

Comment: @THBBFT has nailed it.  Follow exactly what he's done there.

Comment: @THBBFT's thank you verrrrry much , thanks alot ,your code work after you add integer but you forget ')' in the query . thank you rhank you very much

Comment: If an answer solved the problem you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

For starters use a parametrized SQL statement.  That will both make your code more secure and potentially get rid of the error.

```
        str = "select bank_name from bank, rate, [user] where((bank.bank_id=rate.bank_id)and(user.user_id=rate.user_id=@UserName";
        com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        object obj = Session["UserName"]; // add watch and break point
        int username = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", username ));
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
```

*Disclaimer: There is no error handling on this code sample, wrap this in a try/catch before trying this in production code*

Comment: sorry ,i'm not proffisional....the error that appear when decleare string (((Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)))

Comment: @NailaMohammad, awesome ... that means I'm wring about the implicit conversion to string.  Edited code.

Comment: 's  the error of string is correct but the old error is still appear 
((Incorrect syntax near '='.)) .... i want to tell you something maybe help us that id is integer in the database . but in session variable is taken from text box.

Comment: @NailaMohammad and tada ... explicit casting an object to an `int`.  The risk here is that your `Object` isn't really an `int`.

Comment: 's now the error is (Input string was not in a correct format. ) and the line (intuser name) line is red.

Comment: @NailaMohammad  sounds like your `Session["username"]` is null https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: 's  thanks alot for your help,  code is still not work.

Comment: thank you very much .thanks alot your code after you add integer variable is correct .only you forget ')' in the query.thank you for your help @THBBFT's

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have invalid syntax.   Try this:

```
str = "select bank_name from bank, rate, [user] where((bank.bank_id=rate.bank_id)and(user.user_id=rate.user_id) AND (user.user_id='" + Session["UserName"] + "'))";
```

Comment: Please, don't go suggesting a solution that's **utterly** open and prone to **SQL Injection** attacks! If you suggest something - please suggest something *reasonable* (parametrized queries)

Answer (score 0):

This the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SqlConnectioncon=newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMConnectionString"].ConnectionString);


   String SQL = "SELECT UserName,Password FROM Login";
   SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
   DataSet login = new DataSet();
   Adpt.Fill(login);

   foreach (DataRow dr in login.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
       Label3.Text += login.Tables[0].Rows[0]["USerName"].ToString() + "<br />";
       Label4.Text += login.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Password"].ToString() + "<br />";

   }
  }
```